# Angular, Karma (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) - [Separate Src/Build]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-runner, systemjs

I'm working with a build system using Angular(2), typescript, karma and SystemJs.

The application build works perfectly taking the src files from apps/samples/** to build/** this is the structure of the build directory. I run my gulp task build the files and browser-sync presents me with my app :)

```
apps/
  samples/
    app/
      app.component.ts
      app.module.ts
      main.ts
    assets/
      scss/
      js/ //@angular and other node libs get kept here
    test/
      app.component.spec.ts
    index.html
    systemjs.config.js
    systemjs.config.extras.js    
build/
  app/
    app.component.js
    app.component.js.map
    app.module.js
    app.module.js.map
    main.js
    main.js.map
  assets/
    css/
    js/ //@angular and other node libs get kept here
  test/
    app.component.spec.js
    app.component.spec.js.map
  index.html
  systemjs.config.js
  systemjs.config.extras.js
Gulpfile.babel.js
karma.conf.js
karma-test-shim.js
package.json
```

Now as mentioned before I have no problems with typescript or any other part of the build the problem comes when running karma I keep getting an error as follows:

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', '; Zone:', '<root>', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error{stack: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', message: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', originalStack: 'Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', zoneAwareStack: 'Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', name: 'Error', toString: function toString() { ... }, originalErr: Error{stack: 'Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', message: 'XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', originalStack: 'Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', zoneAwareStack: 'Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js', name: 'Error', toString: function toString() { ... }}}, '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/systemjs.config.js'
```

Now i've been working from a combination of the angular quickstart project and a tutorial here https://www.agvision.ro/angular-2-karma-jasmine-unit-testing/

Here is my karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {

var appBase    = 'build/app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
var appSrcBase = 'apps/samples/app//';       // app source TS files
var appAssets  = '/build/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

// Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
var testingBase    = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
        builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
        // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
        // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
        Chrome_travis_ci: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    },

    files: [
        // System.js for module loading
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

        // Polyfills
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

        // zone.js
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
        // RxJs
        { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

        // Paths loaded via module imports:
        // Angular itself
        { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

        { pattern: 'build/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: 'build/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
        'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

        // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
        { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
        { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


        // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
        // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
        { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
        { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

        // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
        { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
        // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
        "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
})
}
```

and here is my karma-test-shim.js

```
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// builtPaths: root paths for output ("built") files
// get from karma.config.js, then prefix with '/base/' (default is 'app/')
var builtPaths = (__karma__.config.builtPaths || ['app/'])
.map(function (p) {
    return '/base/build/' + p;
});

__karma__.loaded = function () {
};

function isJsFile(path) {
    return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
    return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

// Is a "built" file if is JavaScript file in one of the "built" folders
function isBuiltFile(path) {
    return isJsFile(path) &&
        builtPaths.reduce(function (keep, bp) {
            return keep || (path.substr(0, bp.length) === bp);
    }, false);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
    .filter(isSpecFile)
    .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
    baseURL: 'base/',
    // Extend usual application package list with test folder
    packages: {'testing': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}},

    // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
    // Map the angular testing umd bundles
    map: {
        '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
    },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js').then(function (m) {
    console.log(m);
})
//.then(importSystemJsExtras)
.then(initTestBed)
.then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
 function importSystemJsExtras() {
     return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
         .catch(function (reason) {
             console.log(
              'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
        );
        console.log(reason);
    });
}

 function initTestBed() {
    return Promise.all([
        System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
        System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
    ])

    .then(function (providers) {
        var coreTesting = providers[0];
        var browserTesting = providers[1];

        coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
            browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting() {
    return Promise.all(
        allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
        return System.import(moduleName);
    })
)
    .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

Now im getting the error and have read post after post after post some mention the base/ directory that karma puts files in, some have mentioned packages and modules and more but nowere gives a definitive answer as to why karma wont load system js.

Im a neewb with angular2 and prefer the build strucutre so wont be changing that aspect, anything else would be helpfull even if im missing something really simple.

Comment: Did you get this working? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
{ pattern: 'build/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'build/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false }
```

to:

```
{ pattern: '/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: '/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false }
```